# When you refine a search with a 'site:' operator, Google shows results from all the indexed pages from the website that you specified

Tags: google-search

https://www.google.com/search?q=study+PHYSICS+site%3Aedu+-jiwaji&biw=1695&bih=1079&tbs=qdr%3Ad&tbm=nws&ei=Yoa6YdHgC-qfptQP4se20AY&ved=0ahUKEwjRmZ-ohuf0AhXqj4kEHeKjDWo4ChDh1QMIDA&uact=5&oq=study+PHYSICS+site%3Aedu+-jiwaji&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LW5ld3MQA1CFBVj1C2CNDWgAcAB4AIAB4AGIAZoGkgEFNi4xLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-news

Google search cannot search for news articles in the last 24 hours when using filters anymore. You can easily see that it includes results from last year or even before that and bogus pages that aren't news. I also can't remove certain sites, I want only sites with .edu. This link worked yesterday, but Google decided to not support the site: operator anymore when searching for news.

I am not sure why, but Google has become absolutely terrible and I am trying to find alternatives, because they removed a lot of features and it seems like sometimes 90% of the results are missing.

Comment: 1. Instead of deleting and posting a slightly different question it's better to edit the previous question (you might get banned by the system to post new questions until you fix some of the deleted questions). 2. If you need help to learn the ropes of this site or help to improve your question post a question on [meta] including a link to the question you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Getting no results when searching for news in the last 24 hours during a weekend using `site:edu` might be completely normal, specially for science / academic related keywords.

Now (Monday afternoon) I'm getting 7 results.

Try using other filters like Past week or wait or keep trying until you get some results.